# Out of bounds error Index 99 Size 1

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am doing a program that solves expressions. I have made it work but when the code reads through the division sign "/" it comes out as `index out of bounds`, and I don't know how to fix it. May ask you great java minds to see and give me tips on what to do? I don't want the answer just tips so I could learn.

Thank You!

The main class of my program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class ExpressionSolver
{
    int answer;
    String expString;
    ArrayList<String> exp;
    public ExpressionSolver(String s)
    {
        setExpression(s);
    }
    public void setExpression(String s)
    {
        expString = s;
        exp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String temp: s.split(" "))
        {
         exp.add(temp);
        }
    }
    public void solveExpression()
    { 
       int index1, index2, num1, num2;        
      while(exp.contains("*") || exp.contains("/"))
      {
           index1 = exp.indexOf("*");
           index2 = 0;
           if(index1 <= 0)
           {
             index1 = exp.indexOf("/");
             index2 = 1;
           }
         num1 = Integer.parseInt(exp.get(index1-1));
         num2 = Integer.parseInt(exp.get(index1+1));
        if(index2 == 0)
         {
            answer = num1 * num2;
         }
         else
         {
            answer = num1 / num2;
         }
         exp.remove(index1 - 1);
         exp.remove(index1 - 1);
         exp.set(index1 - 1, Integer.toString(answer));
      }
      while(exp.contains("+") || exp.contains("-"))
      {
           index1 = exp.indexOf("+");
           index2 = 0;
           if(index1 <= 0)
           {
             index1 = exp.indexOf("-");
          index2 = 1;
           }
         num1 = Integer.parseInt(exp.get(index1-1));
         num2 = Integer.parseInt(exp.get(index1+1));
        if(index2 == 0)
         {
            answer = num1 + num2;
         }
         else
         {
            answer = num1 - num2;
         }
         exp.remove(index1 - 1);
         exp.remove(index1 - 1);
         exp.set(index1 - 1, Integer.toString(answer));
      }
}
  public String toString()   
  {
   return expString + " = " + answer;
  }
}
```

my runner class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ExpressionSolverRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {  
      ExpressionSolver test = new ExpressionSolver("3 + 3");
      test.solveExpression();
      System.out.println(test);

      test.setExpression("3 * 5");
      test.solveExpression();
      System.out.println(test);

      test.setExpression("3 - 5");
      test.solveExpression();
      System.out.println(test);

      test.setExpression("3 / 5");
      test.solveExpression();
      System.out.println(test);
    }  

}
```

My output

```
----jGRASP exec: java ExpressionSolverRunner
3 + 3 = 6
3 * 5 = 15
3 - 5 = -2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 99, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:444)
    at ExpressionSolver.solveExpression(ExpressionSolver.java:60)
    at ExpressionSolverRunner.main(ExpressionSolverRunner.java:29)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Whenever the program reads `3 / 5` it comes the out of bounds error. The answer is supposed to be 0.

Comment: what statement corresponds to line 60 in 'solveExpression'

Answer (score 0):

Some hints regarding your code in general:

1. For analysing the problem it would help if the code reflects exactly the code you used while producing the stack trace. Line numbers indicate that this is not the case.
2. `if(index1 <= 0)`: Don't get this: if `index1 == 0` it means that there was a match (first character of the string you tested). I suppose you want something like `if(index1 < 0)`

   To be honest I don't understand why the `-` test didn't throw an exception. Maybe the code you posted isn't in sync with the test result?
3. What you call `index2` is not an index but logically a boolean. It seems that you're still evaluating it correctly but it would improve readability of the code massively if you use a boolean and a different name (e.g. `boolean index1DidNotMatch` or something like this)

There are more things we could discuss, but since you wanted some tipps maybe what I wrote will help you a bit to solve the problem.

Comment: Your tips helped me, and I got the program to print the output without any exception error, but I have a little problem. When I added an extra test case which is 
5 / 5 * 2 + 8 / 2 + 5 I get an answer of 17 and not 11..